# Spring batch: Late binding with Step Scope not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to run a simple example of Spring Batch, however I am having trouble with late-binding of parameters in the `ItemReader`.

I've annotated the `ItemReader` with the `step` scope as pointed out in the documentation, however I am getting an exception because `FileSystemResource` is trying to open the file with a `null` value.

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.<init>(FileSystemResource.java:80) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.suntecgroup.fileinjester.config.BatchJobConfig.reader(BatchJobConfig.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job ingestFile( Step ingestRecords) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("ingestFile")
                .flow(ingestRecords)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step ingestRecords(ItemReader<CustomerRecord> reader
            , ItemWriter<CustomerRecord> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("ingestRecords")
                .<CustomerRecord, CustomerRecord> chunk(100)
                .reader(reader)
                //.processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<CustomerRecord> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.path']}") String filePath) {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<CustomerRecord>()
                .name("customerRecordReader")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(filePath))
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name", "email", "profession", "type")
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<CustomerRecord>() {{
                    setTargetType(CustomerRecord.class);
                }})
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<CustomerRecord> writer() {
        return new ConsoleWriter();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share how you launch your job and pass parameters to it? Are you sure the job parameter `input.file.path` is passed in and is not null?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I'm not actually starting the job, this happens after spring is initialized. On further reading, I think `Spring Boot` automatically starts all the configured jobs, on disabling that it seems to be working.